# Filtering data in excel without having to use 'Filter'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter the data in my table based on month. It has a date cell. I know I can use the filter option, however I don't want to go through that method to decide which month to select. I would rather have a more user friendly drop down box through which I select the month and the data shown is of that month only. Does anybody know how I could implement this? Open to using macros and VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an example of technique........you will have to modify this to meet your needs.  Say we have:

[image]

With the data validation pull-down in cell **C1**.  Put this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim t As Range, mn As Variant
   Set t = Range("C1")
   If Intersect(t, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   mn = t.Value
   Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
   If mn = 0 Or mn = "" Then Exit Sub

   For i = 2 To 24
      mnt = Month(Cells(i, 1).Value)
      If mnt <> mn Then
         Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

The macro will monitor your selection and display/hide rows accordingly.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**